# Can I use the same"radioButton_states" drawable and create a radioGroup that has different background colors each button?

Tags: android, xml, radio-button, customization, radio-group

I am trying to create a radioGroup that has different colors for each of the radio buttons "unchecked" state.

Eg.
[image]

Currently I have.

CreateRadioButtonsRow() tries to create a row of `RadioButtons` as a `RadioGroup` in a `linearLayout`.

```
 ColorChooser.java (important function from class)

private Dialog colorChooserDialog;
private Context context;

private LinearLayout linearLayoutColors;
private int[] colorChooserColors;
private Drawable radioButtonBackground;


 private void CreateRadioButtonRow()
{
    final RadioButton [] radioButtons = new RadioButton[6];
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(context);
    radioGroup.setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton(context);
        setDrawableBackgroundColor(colorChooserColors[i]);
        radioButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio_button_states);
        radioButtons[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.null_selector);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButtons[i]);
    }
    linearLayoutColors.addView(radioGroup);
}

private void setDrawableBackgroundColor(int color)
{
    if (radioButtonBackground instanceof ShapeDrawable)
    {
        ((ShapeDrawable)radioButtonBackground).getPaint().setColor(color);
    }
    else if (radioButtonBackground instanceof GradientDrawable)
    {
        ((GradientDrawable)radioButtonBackground).setColor(color);
    }
}
```

**radio_button_states.xml** contains the checked and unchecked drawables.

```
radio_button_states.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_button_enabled"/>

    <item android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_button_background"/>
</selector>
```

**color_radio_button_enabled.xml** is the enabled state which is basically the unchecked circle shape with a white ring around it.

```
color_radio_button_enabled.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/color_radio_button_background"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/selected_ring"/>
</layer-list>
```

**Selected_Ring.xml** is the white ring layer

```
selected_ring.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2"
    android:thickness="2dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <size
        android:width="40dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="#ffffff"/>
</shape>
```

**color_radio_button_background.xml** is a colored circle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
    <size android:width="40dp"
          android:height="40dp"/>
</shape>
```

**colors.xml** is used to populate the int [] colorChooserColors

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="c0" type="color">#ff9999</item>
    <item name="c1" type="color">#ff4d4d</item>
    <item name="c2" type="color">#ff0000</item>
    <item name="c3" type="color">#cc0000</item>
    <item name="c4" type="color">#990000</item>
    <item name="c5" type="color">#660000</item>
    <integer-array name="array_chooser_colors">
        <item>@color/c0</item>
        <item>@color/c1</item>
        <item>@color/c2</item>
        <item>@color/c3</item>
        <item>@color/c4</item>
        <item>@color/c5</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

What this produces is:

[image]

It seems that the color never gets saved and the radio_button_states only uses the last set color.

Do I need to set a different drawable button_states for each of these buttons? or is there a way I can save each colored background to each radioButton's `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio_button_states)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All **Resource Drawable**s (*R.drawable.**) are static by nature, so when you change the color using `getPaint().setColor(color)` for one **RadioButton**, it will be changed for all of them.

I wasn't able to fully grasp what you are doing with the `instanceOf` code since it looks like you only are using shape **Drawable**s, so I don't have a complete solution...but I have an approach for you.

Rather than using **Resource Drawables**, create a new **Drawable** instance for each button. In example, change the private void `setDrawableBackgroundColor(int color)` to accept a **RadioButton**, and attach a new background **Drawable** on the fly. See here:

```
//------------------
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton(context);

    //The line below is undoing the setDrawableBackgroundColor line
    //radioButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio_button_states);

    //Didn't have the file for this one...
    //radioButtons[i].setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.null_selector);

    //Notice how now we pass a RadioButton to the below method
    setDrawableBackgroundColor(colorChooserColors[i], radioButtons[i]);

    radioGroup.addView(radioButtons[i]);
}
//------------------
private void setDrawableBackgroundColor(int color, RadioButton radio) {

    //We are now creating a new ShapeDrawable instance for each individual 
    //button - so now they will all have their own individual Drawable, 
    //rather than sharing the same static one.

    Drawable radioButtonBackground = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());

    ((ShapeDrawable) radioButtonBackground).getPaint().setColor(color);

    radio.setBackground(radioButtonBackground);
}
```

I don't think this will fully solve your issue, but I hope it puts you in the right direction. I tried the above code and got the following result (I tweaked the colors.xml slightly for effect).

[image: My emulator with your code, tweaked]